# Apache Camel pool on email doesn't return attachments

Tags: java, csv, email, ssl, apache-camel

This is my first post and english is not my native language, so please don't be cruel.
As i explained in the title I have a program that poll my mail with Apache Camel, and if there's a csv file in the attachments the program take it and process it. When i take the attachments from the email the method exchange.getIn().getAttachments() return an empty container, but I am pretty sure that the email is beeing readed. I am almost sure that I am not doing something regargins SSL but I don't really know what to do.

I am using Java OSGI with annotations and this bundles included:

- org.apache.camel.camel-core 2.15.6
- org.apache.camel.camel-mail 2.15.6
- com.sun.mail.imap  1.6.0
- com.sun.mail.javax.mail 1.6.0
- javax.mail.api 1.6.0

The source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Spronghi/sensorsystem). Interesting classes are listed below:

**ConfigReaderFactory** take the email informations via ConfigAdmin and build the url.

```
@org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component(name = "factory", property = "service.pid=it.sensorsystem.core.config.factory", configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.IGNORE)
public class ConfigReaderFactory implements ManagedServiceFactory {
    private static final String DELETE_CONDITIONS = "readLock=changed&idempotent=false&noop=true&delete=true";
    private static final String NON_DELETE_CONDITIONS = "noop=true";

    private volatile DependencyManager dependencyManager;
    private final Map<String, Component> components = new HashMap<>();
    private String url;
    private String name;
    private int confLine;
    private String endpointType;
    private String ip;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String folder;
    private boolean delete;
    private CamelService camel;
    private TypeConverter converter;
    private EventPublisher publisher;
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;
    private String email;

    @Reference(service = TypeConverter.class)
    public void setTypeConverter(TypeConverter converter) {
        this.converter = converter;
    }

    public void unsetTypeConverter(TypeConverter converter) {
        this.converter = null;
    }

    @Reference(service = EventPublisher.class)
    public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public void unsetEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = null;
    }

    @Reference(service = CamelService.class)
    public void setCamelService(CamelService camel) {
        this.camel = camel;
    }

    public void unsetCamelService(CamelService camel) {
        this.camel = null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.getClass().getName();
    }

    @Override
    public void updated(String pid, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Dictionary props) throws ConfigurationException {
        if (components.containsKey(pid)) {
            return;
        }
        if (props != null) {
            List<String> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> csvTypes = new ArrayList<>();

            int count = 1;
            String configurationLine;
            while ((configurationLine = (String) props.get(Integer.toString(count++))) != null) {
                List<String> values = Utils.getValuesFromLine(configurationLine);
                attributes.add(values.size() >= 1 ? values.get(0) : TypeConverter.NAMELESS);
                csvTypes.add(values.size() >= 2 ? values.get(1) : TypeConverter.NAMELESS);
            }
            confLine = Integer.parseInt((String) props.get(Config.CONFIG_LINE));
            name = (String) props.get(Config.NAME);

            initConfigParameters(props);
            buildURL();
            System.out.println("[URL] " + url);

            try {
                Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(Constants.ATTRIBUTES, attributes);
                params.put(Constants.TYPES, csvTypes);
                params.put(Constants.CONF_LINE, confLine);
                params.put(Constants.SOURCE, name);
                params.put(Constants.PUBLISHER, publisher);
                params.put(Constants.CONVERTER, converter);
                params.put(Constants.LATITUDE, latitude);
                params.put(Constants.LONGITUDE, longitude);
                params.put(Constants.ENDPOINT_TYPE, endpointType);
                params.put(Constants.EMAIL, email);
                Processor processor = new CSVProcessor(params);
                camel.start(FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext(), processor, url);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleted(String pid) {
        Component component = components.remove(pid);
        dependencyManager.remove(component);
        component.stop();
    }

    private void buildURL() {
        url = "";
        switch(endpointType) {
        case Constants.FTP:
            url += "ftp://" + username + "@" + ip + "/" + folder + "?";
            if(!password.equals("")) {
                url += "password=" + password + "&";
            }
            break;
        case Constants.FILE:
            url += "file://" + folder + "?";
            break;
        case Constants.EMAIL:
            url += "imaps://imap.gmail.com?username="+email+"&password="+password
                    +"&delete=false&unseen=false&consumer.delay=100";
        }
        if(endpointType.equals(Constants.FTP) || endpointType.equals(Constants.FILE)) {
            if (delete) {
                url += DELETE_CONDITIONS;
            } else {
                url += NON_DELETE_CONDITIONS;
            }
        }

    }

    private void initConfigParameters(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Dictionary props) {
        confLine = Integer.parseInt((String) props.get(Config.CONFIG_LINE));
        name = (String) props.get(Config.NAME);
        endpointType = (String) props.get(Config.ENDPOINT_TYPE);
        ip = (String) props.get(Config.IP_ADDRESS);
        username = (String) props.get(Config.USERNAME);
        password = (String) props.get(Config.PASSWORD);
        folder = (String) props.get(Config.FOLDER);
        email = (String) props.get(Config.EMAIL);
        delete = ((String) props.get(Config.DELETE)).equals("true");
        if((String) props.get(Config.LATITUDE)!=null) {
            latitude = Double.parseDouble((String) props.get(Config.LATITUDE));
        } 
        if((String) props.get(Config.LONGITUDE)!=null) {
            longitude = Double.parseDouble((String) props.get(Config.LONGITUDE));
        }

        printParameters();
    }

    private void printParameters() {
        System.out.println("\nStarting camel with parameters:");
        System.out.println("[sensor_name]::" + name);
        System.out.println("[latitude]::" + latitude);
        System.out.println("[longitude]::" + longitude);
        System.out.println("[endpoint_type]::" + endpointType);
        if(endpointType.equals("ftp")) {
            System.out.println("[ip_address]::" + ip);
            System.out.println("[folder]::" + folder);
            System.out.println("[user]::" + username);
            System.out.println("[password]::" + password);
        } else if(endpointType.equals("file")) {
            System.out.println("[folder]::" + folder);
        } else if(endpointType.equals("email")) {
            System.out.println("[email]::" + email);
            System.out.println("[password]::" + password);
        }
        System.out.println("[delete]::" + delete);
    }
}
```

**CSVProcessor** take the attachments from the email and process the .csv files.

```
public class CSVProcessor implements Processor{
    private List<String> attributes;
    private List<String> csvTypes;
    private int confLine;
    private String source;
    private String endpointType;
    private TypeConverter converter;
    private EventPublisher publisher;
    private Long timestamp;
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public CSVProcessor(Map<String, Object> params) {
        this.attributes = (List<String>) params.get(Constants.ATTRIBUTES);
        this.csvTypes = (List<String>) params.get(Constants.TYPES);
        this.confLine = (int) params.get(Constants.CONF_LINE);
        this.source = (String) params.get(Constants.SOURCE);
        this.publisher = (EventPublisher) params.get(Constants.PUBLISHER);
        this.converter = (TypeConverter) params.get(Constants.CONVERTER);
        this.latitude = (Double) params.get(Constants.LATITUDE);
        this.longitude = (Double) params.get(Constants.LONGITUDE);
        this.endpointType = (String) params.get(Constants.ENDPOINT_TYPE);
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        if(endpointType.equals(Constants.EMAIL)) {
            Map<String, DataHandler> attachments = exchange.getIn().getAttachments();
            System.out.println("Detected email [attachments: "+exchange.getIn().getAttachments().size()+"]");
            System.out.println("[BODY]\n"+exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
            if(exchange.getIn().hasAttachments()) {
                System.out.println("Detected email attachments: "+attachments);
                for(String name : attachments.keySet()) {
                    DataHandler dh = attachments.get(name);
                    String filename = dh.getName();
                    System.out.println("Detected email attachment with name: "+filename);
                    if(filename.contains(".csv")) {
                       processBody(exchange.getContext().getTypeConverter()
                               .convertTo(String.class, dh.getInputStream()));
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            processBody(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
        }

    }
    private void processBody(String body) {
        int count = 1;
        for(String line : Utils.getLines(body)){
            if(count++>confLine){
                for(IOTEvent event: processLine(line)){
                    publisher.publish(event);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private boolean processTimeAndPosition(String line) {
        Iterator<String> valueIterator = Utils.getValuesFromLine(line).iterator();
        Iterator<String> attributeIterator = attributes.iterator();
        Iterator<String> typeIterator = csvTypes.iterator();
        boolean systemTimestamp = true;


        while(attributeIterator.hasNext()){
            String attribute = attributeIterator.next();
            String type = typeIterator.next();
            String value = valueIterator.next();
            switch(attribute.toLowerCase()){
            case Constants.TIMESTAMP:
                systemTimestamp = false;
                timestamp = (Long) converter.convert(type, value);
                break;
            case Constants.LATITUDE:
                latitude = (Double) converter.convert(type, value);
                break;
            case Constants.LONGITUDE:
                longitude = (Double) converter.convert(type, value);
                break;
            }
        }
        return systemTimestamp;
    }

    private List<IOTEvent> processLine(String line){
        Iterator<String> valueIterator = Utils.getValuesFromLine(line).iterator();
        Iterator<String> attributeIterator = attributes.iterator();
        Iterator<String> typeIterator = csvTypes.iterator();
        List<IOTEvent> IOTEvents = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean systemTimestamp = processTimeAndPosition(line);

        // Resetting iterators
        valueIterator = Utils.getValuesFromLine(line).iterator();
        attributeIterator = attributes.iterator();
        typeIterator = csvTypes.iterator();

        while(attributeIterator.hasNext()){
            String attribute = attributeIterator.next();
            String type = typeIterator.next();
            String value = valueIterator.next();

            switch(attribute.toLowerCase()){
            case Constants.TIMESTAMP:
            case Constants.LATITUDE:
            case Constants.LONGITUDE:
                continue;
            }

            IOTEvent iotEvent = new IOTEvent();
            iotEvent.setSource(source);
            iotEvent.setValue(new Value(type, converter.convert(type, value)));
            if(systemTimestamp) {
                iotEvent.setCdate(new Date());
            } else {
                iotEvent.setCdate(new Date(timestamp));
            }
            iotEvent.setType(attribute);
            iotEvent.setSystemCDate(systemTimestamp);
            if(latitude!=null && longitude!=null )
                iotEvent.setPoint(new Point(latitude, longitude));

            IOTEvents.add(iotEvent);
        }

        return IOTEvents;
    }
}
```

**DefaultCamelService** starts camel:

```
@Component(immediate=true)
public class DefaultCamelService implements CamelService{
    private CamelContext camelContext=null;
    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context, Processor processor, String url) throws Exception {
        if(camelContext==null) {
            camelContext = new OsgiDefaultCamelContext(context);
        }
        camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from(url).process(processor);
            }
        });
        try {
            camelContext.start();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error connecting to endpoint:"+url);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        camelContext.stop();

    }
}
```

This is the result on console that regards email:

```
Connecting to MailStore: imaps://imap.gmail.com:993 (SSL enabled), folder=INBOX
Getting folder INBOX
Polling mailbox folder: imaps://imap.gmail.com:993 (SSL enabled), folder=INBOX
Configured property: peek on bean: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage@6dd74603 with value: true
Fetching 1 messages. Total 1 messages.
Processing message: messageNumber=[1], from=[Simone Colaci <sim.colaci@gmail.com>], to=[sensorsystem.csv@gmail.com], subject=[csv testing], sentDate=[Sep 14, 2017 1:15:24 PM], receivedDate=[Sep 14, 2017 1:15:45 PM]
Detected email [attachments: 0]
Close mailbox folder INBOX from imaps://imap.gmail.com:993 (SSL enabled), folder=INBOX
```

Please help me, remember that this is my first post and english is not my native language. I checked everything on internet.
Thank you.

Edit 1:
This is the body of the email sent by my Gmail account to sensorsystem.csv@gmail.com:

```
[BODY]
--94eb2c19b976cd06bd055924656c
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="94eb2c19b976cd06ba055924656a"

--94eb2c19b976cd06ba055924656a
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

Hi,
this is a csv file

--94eb2c19b976cd06ba055924656a
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<div dir="ltr"><div>Hi,<br></div>this is a csv file<br><div><div><div class="gmail_quote"><br><div dir="ltr"><br></div>
</div><br></div></div></div>

--94eb2c19b976cd06ba055924656a--
--94eb2c19b976cd06bd055924656c
Content-Type: text/csv; charset="US-ASCII"; name="esrlNcepRe_LonPM180_e063_990c_26e6.csv"
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename="esrlNcepRe_LonPM180_e063_990c_26e6.csv"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: f_j7kc6dcl0

dGltZSxsYXRpdHVkZSxsb25naXR1ZGUsYWlyLHByZXMKVVRDLGRlZ3JlZXNfbm9ydGgsZGVncmVl
c19lYXN0LGRlZ0ssUGFzY2FscwoyMDAyLTA3LTAxVDAwOjAwOjAwWiw0Mi41LC0xNDcuNSwyODcu
MSwxMDIyNzAuMAo=
--94eb2c19b976cd06bd055924656c--
```

Edit 2:
Tried with latest Camel libraries listed below but result is the same:

- org.apache.camel.camel-core 2.19.3
- org.apache.camel.camel-mail 2.19.3

Edit 3: 
Debug also give this warnings from Java Mail:

```
Sep 18, 2017 10:20:59 AM javax.mail.Session loadResource
WARNING: expected resource not found: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
Sep 18, 2017 10:20:59 AM javax.mail.Session loadResource
WARNING: expected resource not found: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
```

Comment: Given the debug output it obviously gets an email but does not find an attachment in it. Can you provide  a sample of the email received (as source) to show how the attachment you are looking for is stored inside the email? Because maybe there is something wrong in the email and not in your code.

Comment: I edited the post with the body of the email that Camel returns. Is it correct or did you want something else?

Comment: Also try with latest Apache Camel release to see if it works.

Comment: Tried with Camel 2.19.3 that I think it's the latest release but result is the same

Comment: Run outside OSGi in a plain standalone or junit test and see if it works there. OSGi can be very tricky runtime platform with classloading problems and whatnot so its always good to test outside OSGi

Comment: I will do it but i reallt need the OSGI context there